# Combine multiple select with update

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, subquery

I have a query that is dragging down my application. There has to be a way to improve this by joining the update with the selects. Any help appreciated. Here is the very slow query:

```
Select t1.id, t2.tracker from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.tracker is not null
```

The above returns a row set I can process. For each row that is returned, I check tracker in a 
third table to see if only 1 row exists:

```
select tracker from Table3 where tracker="from above query".
```

If tracker has a count of 1 row in Table 3, I then perform an update on Table 1.

```
Update Table 1, set some field where id=t1.id
```

How do I combine this? The answer listed is wonderful, but I guess the question wasn't made clear enough. Therefore, I have edited the question.

Table 1 returns the possible list of ID's to update.
Table 2 returns the tracker I need to search Table 3.
Table 3 tells me if the tracker exists only once, so I can use this to go back to Table 1 and
update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a `HAVING` clause and an additional `LEFT JOIN`, you can combine the first two queries into one returning the `tracker` only for those with one record in `Table3` with an expression like `HAVING COUNT(t3.tracker) = 1`

The `SELECT` portion then looks like:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t2.tracker
FROM 
  -- Your original comma-separated FROM clause (implicit inner join)
  -- has been replaced with a more modern explicit INNER JOIN, which
  -- works more clearly with the LEFT JOIN we need to do.
  Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  -- left join table 3 by tracker value
  LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.tracker = t3.tracker
WHERE t2.tracker IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  t1.id,
  t2.tracker
-- limit the group to only those with 1 tracker in t3
HAVING COUNT(t3.tracker) = 1
```

Now, you *should* be able to stuff that into an `UPDATE` query with a `JOIN`. MySQL's update-join syntax would look like:

```
UPDATE 
  Table1 t_up
  -- join Table1 in its normal form against the query from above
  -- MySQL won't allow an IN () subquery for update in most versions
  -- so it has to be done as a join instead.
  JOIN (
    -- the subquery only needs to return t1.id
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM 
      Table1 t1
      INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
      LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.tracker = t3.tracker
    -- Filter to those with non-null t2.tracker
    WHERE t2.tracker IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      -- Since only id was in SELECT, only id needs to be in GROUP BY
      t1.id
    HAVING COUNT(t3.tracker) = 1
  ) t_set ON t_up.id = t_set.id
SET t_up.some_field = 'SOME NEW VALUE'
```

### [Here is a demonstration of the concept in action...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/056d0/1)

Comment: tracker field is not in Table 1. It exists only in Table 2 and Table 3. So the left join should be for table 2? Probably my fault for not making this clear, sorry.

Comment: Okay then, I'll update it accordingly in a few minutes.

Comment: @user3314053 okay, I made the changes above and in the sqlfiddle example. It's only really a matter of changing the `ON` condition in the `LEFT JOIN` to `t2.tracker = t3.tracker`.. I actually wondered about this, because it didn't make sense to me that the `tracker` would be in all 3 tables.  Anyway, based on my test it does seem to work.

Comment: Works much faster! Thanks